# Can't save option for custom option type for 'test'

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1

I have created new custom option type as test but it does not save in database can you suggest for the same ?

Following code I have used to modify CustomOptions.php

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\ActionDelete;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;


class CustomOptions extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions
{
    const FIELD_TYPE_TEST_NAME = 'test';
    protected function getStaticTypeContainerConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
                        'breakLine' => false,
                        'showLabel' => false,
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-group-columns admin__control-group-equal',
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'fieldTemplate' => 'Magento_Catalog/form/field',
                        'visible' => false,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME => $this->getPriceFieldConfig(10),
                static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME => $this->getPriceTypeFieldConfig(20),
                static::FIELD_SKU_NAME => $this->getSkuFieldConfig(30),
                static::FIELD_MAX_CHARACTERS_NAME => $this->getMaxCharactersFieldConfig(40),
                static::FIELD_FILE_EXTENSION_NAME => $this->getFileExtensionFieldConfig(50),
                static::FIELD_IMAGE_SIZE_X_NAME => $this->getImageSizeXFieldConfig(60),
                static::FIELD_IMAGE_SIZE_Y_NAME => $this->getImageSizeYFieldConfig(70),
                static::FIELD_TYPE_TEST_NAME => $this->getTemplateTypeFieldConfig(80)
            ]
        ];
    }

    protected function getTypeFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Option Type'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/js/custom-options-type',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
                        'selectType' => 'optgroup',
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_TYPE_NAME,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'options' => $this->getProductOptionTypes(),
                        'disableLabel' => true,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'selectedPlaceholders' => [
                            'defaultPlaceholder' => __('-- Please select --'),
                        ],
                        'validation' => [
                            'required-entry' => true,
                        ],
                        'groupsConfig' => [
                            'text' => [
                                'values' => ['field', 'area'],
                                'indexes' => [
                                    static::CONTAINER_TYPE_STATIC_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_SKU_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_MAX_CHARACTERS_NAME,
                                ],
                            ],
                            'file' => [
                                'values' => ['file'],
                                'indexes' => [
                                    static::CONTAINER_TYPE_STATIC_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_SKU_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_FILE_EXTENSION_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_IMAGE_SIZE_X_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_IMAGE_SIZE_Y_NAME,
                                ],
                            ],
                            'test' => [
                                'values' => ['test'],
                                'indexes' => [
                                    static::CONTAINER_TYPE_STATIC_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_TYPE_TEST_NAME


                                ],
                            ],
                            'select' => [
                                'values' => ['drop_down', 'radio', 'checkbox', 'multiple'],
                                'indexes' => [
                                    static::GRID_TYPE_SELECT_NAME,
                                ],
                            ],
                            'data' => [
                                'values' => ['date', 'date_time', 'time'],
                                'indexes' => [
                                    static::CONTAINER_TYPE_STATIC_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME,
                                    static::FIELD_SKU_NAME,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * Get config for "Price Type" field
     *
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @param array $config
     * @return array
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected function getTemplateTypeFieldConfig($sortOrder, array $options = [])
    {
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($this->productOptionsPrice->toOptionArray());exit;
        $arr[0]['value'] = 0;
        $arr[0]['label'] = 'test';
        $arr[1]['value'] = 1;
        $arr[1]['label'] = 'test1';

        return array_replace_recursive(
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Template Option'),
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => static::FIELD_TYPE_TEST_NAME,
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                            'options' => $arr,


                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            $options
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it show any error into log?

Comment: no error in log

Comment: Have you run all the commands and then check?

Comment: yes I run di compile